# Batch : files in directory to variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

My Java application is using .doc files as input :

```
java -jar myApp.jar file1.doc file2.doc etc..
```

I want to automatically look for all the doc files in my current directory, add them to a variable and then launch my java command with all the doc files as input.

Would it be possible to do something like

```
for %%a in (*.doc) do (

    echo %%a >> temp.txt
    set Build=%%a
    )
```

Is there a solution to append text in my variable ? (like set Build+=%%a) ?
Then how would I use my java command ?

```
java -jar myApp.jar %Build%
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "build="
for %%a in (*.kml) do (

    echo %%a >> temp.txt
    set "build=!build! %%a"
)


::remove the ECHO word if the command is ok
echo java -jar myApp.jar %build%
```